# How to move different items inside card using css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this following card made whit html, css and bootstrap-3. The problem is when i try to move the details class on the top right part of the card beside the photo, it won't work. Here is the html code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
 <div class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6">
   <div class="front">
     <div>
       <img class="girlimg" src="girl.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
       <h2 class="activname">Guided hiking tours</h2>
         <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
         SEE DETAILS
         </button>
 
 
     </div>
     <div class="details">
       <div class="duration">
         <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration</i>
       </div>
       <div class="people">
         <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
         <p>Max adults:10</p>
       </div>
       <div class="kids">
         <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
         <p>Max children:3</p>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>   </div>   <br />
```

CSS:

```
 .front{
          width: 475px;
          height: 475px;;
          background-color: #F7F4F2;
          align-items: center;
          margin-left: 20%;
          }
         
         .girlimg{
           max-width: 60%;
           max-height: 100%;
         }
        
         .details{
          display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           justify-content: space-around;
         }
         
         .activname{
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: row;
           margin-left: 10%;
           margin-bottom: 5%;
         
         }
         
         .activbutt{
           background-color: #ffcc66;
           border-radius: 2%;
           display: flex;
           margin-left: 20%;
           font-size: 30px;
         }
```

Comment: Perhaps your intentions aren't very clear. Consider clarifying what your expected result should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is moving the details to the top right position of the card, you should use absolute positioning. Try adding `position: relative;` to the parent div (`div.front`), and to then update your details details class as follows

```
.details{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      right:0;
}
```

If you are trying to align the details div side by side with it's siblings, consider using display:flex; on the parent div ([learn about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) or use bootstrap's innate 'col' classes ([read about it here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-basic)).

```
.front{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
```